# Autocompletion with the #import directive in XCode 4

Tags: autocomplete, import, xcode4.2

The question I'm asking is not a big issue but just a little annoyance with autocompletion using the #import directive in XCode.

I have a workspace with static library and apps using them.
My workspace folder architecture is the following:

```
Workspace dir
\->libs
    \-> lib1
        \-> lib1Object1.h
        \-> lib1Object1.m
        \-> lib1Object2.h
        \-> lib1Object2.m
    \-> lib2
    \-> lib3
\->tests
\->apps
    \-> app1
    \-> app2
```

For every app project I'm adding the *../../libs* path in the *User Header Search Paths* settings.

For every lib project I'm adding the *..* path in the *User Header Search Paths* settings.

This way I can include every header file in any other file with the following directive:

```
#import "lib1/lib1Object1.h"
```

My problem is that the autocompletion does'nt work perfectly because when I start typing *#import "li* it complete with *lib1Object1.h* instead of *lib1/lib1Object1.h*.

Alternatively, when using a framework the autocompletion show the header directory first.

For example, if I type *#import  it completes with AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h*.

Does someone know the rule about autocompletion?